# Django tastypie - long JSON output is truncated causing parsing error

Tags: django, json, serialization, tastypie

I have a RESTful webservice returning large amount of JSON data implemented using django-tastypie. I noticed that JSON is suddenly truncated, the whole output is about 2.1 MB but it should be more than 6MB according to my calculations. For shorter amounts it works fine. I know tastypie is using django JSON serialiser but googling about issues with this serialiser or tastypie for JSON truncation doesn't return any sensible results. I would appreciate any hints of how to debug this issue as currently I don't have many ideas...

Comment: is there any code we can see?

Comment: Do you think paginating the response will affect your application. e.g. you can use http://yourwebsite.com/api/v1/resource/?offset=20&limit=20&format=json to get the response in parts. Here you might also want defined your own limit value. Just a thought.

Comment: I have a similar problem!  JSON response gets truncated at approximately 2.1 MB ( but exact size varies a bit ).  I started having the problem after migrating app to new box and upgrading everything. ( using Django 1.6, but not tastiepie ) I can't find any solution!  Did you solve this?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/979/ :D

Comment: Putting jokes aside - I had installed firefox addone for pritty printing json and it was causing problems for large JSON documents. Disabling it/using different browser/ using wget/curl solved my problem.